# Determine if an array of numbers can divided into a set of k consecutive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given some array nums and a positive integer k, determine if its possible to divide this array into sets of k consecutive numbers.

Example:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4] k = 2
```

Output true since [1,2], [3, 4]

My thoughts is that that size of the array nums has to be divisible by the integer k. But when I use that as the test I fail for this test case:

[15,16,17,18,19,16,17,18,19,20,6,7,8,9,10,3,4,5,6,20] k = 5

I get true but the answer is false and I am not sure why. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
int n = nums.size();
if(n % k == 0)
    return true;

return false;
```

Here are more examples if that helps:

[image]

Comment: Take the array `[2,4,6,8]` and `k = 2`. The size of the array is divisible evenly by `k`, but there are not `k` sequences of consecutive numbers.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Maybe I am not understanding the question. Could you provide an answer if your explanation and perhaps a suggested pseudocode to solving it?

Comment: If your test depends only on the length of the array - and doesn't depend at all on the numbers in the array - then it cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: I am commenting on your statement _My thoughts is that that size of the array nums has to be divisible by the integer k_ That will be true for all solutions, but it may also be true for non-solutions. That can't be your only test.

Comment: For solving the problem, I would think the first step would be to sort the array. Then test the `k` sub-arrays to see if they are sequential

Comment: I guess, the answer to the example is false, because the last number is 20 rather than 7. So the last set of 5 numbers doesn't consist of consecutive numbers.

Comment: @Johnny This wouldn't work, consider an array like [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], k=2. Sorting gives [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], and this doesn't fulfill the condition.

Comment: One thing that is important to know is if the "set of consecutive numbers" must be at least of length 2, or if it can contain just one item.

Comment: I would expect that a set of consecutive numbers might even contain no items. A sensible way to define a set being "consecutive" is that for all `x` in the set, either `x` is the maximum element or `x + 1` is in the set. For sets of size 0 or 1, that's trivially true.

Comment: @sammy For your example, wouldn't a valid solution be `[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]`? I am assuming the sub-arrays need to be consecutive with themselves, not the other arrays. The question needs clarification.

Comment: ...but based on the updated examples, my suggestion of simply sorting it and checking is not enough.

Comment: Please include your examples as text/code, not as an image.

Comment: Sort the array. Count the duplicates of each number. Then form the sequences.

Comment: @user3386109 Can you give me some pseudocode I am not sure what you mean by forming the sequences. How does one do that?

Comment: Did you mean https://www.google.com/search?q=split+array+into+consecutive+subsequences ?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx Ok, I posted a worked example as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem can be solved by sorting the array, counting duplicates, and then verifying the consecutive sequences.

Consider example 2, where k=3 and the array is

```
[3,2,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,9,10,11]
```

After sorting:

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,9,10,11]
```

After counting duplicates (the top line has the unique numbers in the array, the bottom line has the duplicate count for each number):

```
1 2 3 4 5 9 10 11
1 2 3 2 1 1  1  1
```

Now check the sequences. The lowest number is 1, so the sequence [1,2,3] must exist in the array, or the output is false. 1, 2, and 3 all have non-zero counts, so the array *does* contain that sequence. Update the counts to remove that sequence:

```
1 2 3 4 5 9 10 11
0 1 2 2 1 1  1  1
```

Now 2 is the lowest number with a non-zero count, so the next sequence is [2,3,4] and the updated counts are:

```
1 2 3 4 5 9 10 11
0 0 1 1 1 1  1  1
```

Finish up with [3,4,5] and [9,10,11]

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

step1. Use TreeMap to store array elements and their occurrence. Treemap helps us to store the element in sorting orders.

step2. Iterate over treemap until it's not empty.

step3. Takeout the first key (firstKey) from treemap and start searching next K consecutive element.

```
public static boolean isPossibleDivide(int[] arr, int k) {

    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.put(arr[i], map.get(arr[i]) != null ? map.get(arr[i]) + 1 : 1);
    }
    while (!map.isEmpty()) {
        int firstKey = map.firstKey();

        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {

            int key = firstKey + i;

            if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                map.put(key, map.get(key) - 1);

                if (map.get(key) == 0)
                    map.remove(key);
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have a quick question- Input: nums = [1,2,3,4], k = 3
Output: false
Explanation: Each array should be divided in subarrays of size 3.  But in your code you have not validate this logic. Can you explain this one how it's working?

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isPossibleDivide(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    int n = nums.size();
    if(n%k != 0)return false;
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end());
    map<int,int> m;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        m[nums[i]]++;
    }
    int nu = m.size() - k + 1;
    for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++){
        if(!nu)break;
        int x = it->second;
        int l=0;
        map<int,int> :: iterator s = it;
        map<int,int> :: iterator s1 = s ;
        while(l<k){
            s->second = s->second - x;
            s++;
            if(s->first - s1->first !=1 && l<k-1)return false;
            s1++;
            l++;
        }
        nu--;
    }
    /*for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++){
        cout << it->first <<" "<<it->second <<endl;
    }*/
    for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++){
        if(it->second != 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have done this, but I don't know why it is not working

Comment: yea was only able to answer two of these questions, no idea how some people can solve all in less than 20 mins

Comment: Was only able to solve the two first questions. The others are hard and the second question is kinda tricky